# Ошибка с транзакциями Entity Framework (MSSQL 2008)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server

Периодически получаю ошибку при работе с файлами из базы. Используется `Entity Framework`, на базе включён `Filestream` который и используется для хранения файлов. Не могу понять почему вылетает эта ошибка:

> The transaction has been stopped because it conflicted with the execution of a FILESTREAM close operation using the same transaction. The transaction will be rolled back.

Может кто видел подобную ошибку и как то боролся с ней?!

---

Обычно вылетает на `commit` или `SaveChanges`

---

В профилировщике `SQL` я обнаружил следующие записи :
Первая ошибка:

```
        2013-06-26 09:44:00.74 spid10s     Error: 3910, Severity: 16, State: 1.
        2013-06-26 09:44:00.74 spid10s     Transaction context in use by another session
```

Она относится к базе `master`
Остальные ошибки в моей базе.
После этого начинают валятся две ошибки:
    This operation conflicts with another pending operation on this transaction. The operation failed.
    This operation conflicts with another pending operation on this transaction. The operation failed.

И в конце ещё одна ошибка:

```
The transaction has been stopped because it conflicted with the execution of a FILESTREAM close operation using the same transaction.  The transaction will be rolled back.
```

---

Совсем недавно обнаружил, что ошибка выпадает только тогда когда не выполнен следующий запрос, при этом для этого запроса в профилировщике в столбце `DataBaseName='master'`. Вот этот запрос:

```
UPDATE [Docs].[dbo].[Files] SET [file_body] = [file_body].NewFilestreamValue () WHERE [file_body].RowGuid () = @hint OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
```

Я не нашёл что делает функция `NewFilestreamValue()` и где про неё можно почитать, возможно она даст разгадку

Comment: во-первых, ошибка транзакций всегда обычно вылетает на commit. а по сути: вы, случайно, не открываете один и тот же файл несколько раз, не закрывая?

Comment: Создание filestream помещено в блок using по выходу из блока он ведь обязан закрыться! А такое ощущение что он это не успевает сделать!Потому что если filestream вынести из блока using и не закрыть filestream то вылетает та же ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

Все, я понял. Сталкивался с подобной проблемой. Это баг микрософта. У `Stream`, даже при включении в блок `using`, проблемы с `Dispose`. Необходимо руками удалять. Попробуйте.

Вот, например, описание проблемы: [Understanding Streams and their lifetime (Flush, Dispose, Close)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864543/understanding-streams-and-their-lifetime-flush-dispose-close).

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я помню, это ошибка .NET и она лечится патчем KB2255379

Comment: Этот патч для Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0, а я использую  .NET Framework 4.0, так что похоже что он мне не подойдёт!